# how to quit python script after multiprocessing processes are done?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

**Update**: with the help of **dano**, I solved this problem.

I didn't invoke producers with `join()`, it made my script hanging.
Only need to add one line as dano said:

```
...
producer = multiprocessing.Process(target=produce,args=(file_queue,row_queue))
producer.daemon = True
producer.start()
...
```

Old script:

```
import multiprocessing
import Queue

QUEUE_SIZE = 2000


def produce(file_queue, row_queue,):

    while not file_queue.empty():
        src_file = file_queue.get()
        zip_reader = gzip.open(src_file, 'rb')

        try:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(zip_reader, delimiter=SDP_DELIMITER)

            for row in csv_reader:
                new_row = process_sdp_row(row)
                if new_row:
                    row_queue.put(new_row)
        finally:
            zip_reader.close()


def consume(row_queue):
    '''processes all rows, once queue is empty, break the infinit loop'''
    while True:
        try:
            # takes a row from queue and process it
            pass
        except multiprocessing.TimeoutError as toe:
            print "timeout, all rows have been processed, quit."
            break
        except Queue.Empty:
            print "all rows have been processed, quit."
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print "critical error"
            print e
            break


def main(args):

    file_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    row_queue = multiprocessing.Queue(QUEUE_SIZE)

    file_queue.put(file1)
    file_queue.put(file2)
    file_queue.put(file3)

    # starts 3 producers
    for i in xrange(4):
        producer = multiprocessing.Process(target=produce,args=(file_queue,row_queue))
        producer.start()

    # starts 1 consumer
    consumer = multiprocessing.Process(target=consume,args=(row_queue,))
    consumer.start()

    # blocks main thread until consumer process finished
    consumer.join()

    # prints statistics results after consumer is done

    sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

**Purpose**:

I am using `python 2.7` `multiprocessing` to generate 3 producers reading 3 files at the same time, and then put the file lines into a `row_queue` and generate 1 consumer to do more processing about all rows. Print statistics result in main thread after consumer is done, so I use `join()` method. Finally invoke `sys.exit(0)` to quit the script.

**Problem**:
Cannot quit the script.

I tried to replace `sys.exit(0)` with `print "the end"`, "the end" displayed on console. Am I doing something wrong? why the script does not quit, and how to let it quit? Thanks

Comment: There's not enough information here to say for sure, but the most likely problem is one or more of the `Producer` processes are still running. Try making them daemons by adding `producer.daemon = True` before calling `producer.start()`, and see if the script will exit.

Comment: Alternatively, call `join()` for each of the producers as well... assuming they will generally terminate, anyway.

Comment: @twalberg If they eventually terminated, the script would exit without the need to call `join()`. Python implicitly calls `join()` on non-daemon subprocesses when the interpreter exits.

Comment: @dano  I will try the daemon flag, can you explain what's the difference between daemon process and non-daemon process? Thanks

Comment: @twalberg this is just a sample of my code, my real `consume()` method is time-consuming method, it does a lot of work, so I think the consumer is always terminate after the producers, that's why I didn't use `join()` for the producers.

Comment: @haifzhan "I think ..." has led to a lot of software bugs when assumptions have proved to be false. Putting `join()` in for the producers will either prove or disprove your assumption, and may shed additional light on the root cause of your issue as a result. It may not be necessary (most of the time), but explicitly coding your cleanup, including threads/processes/etc. is better than just assuming "it'll happen eventually" in most cases...

Comment: @haifzhan The main process won't wait for `daemon` processes to complete before exiting; it will just terminate them and then exit. It will wait indefinitely for non-daemons to exit before exiting itself.

Comment: @dano  thanks for your help, the script can quit after set producers as daemon!

Comment: @twalberg you are right. I should not assume anything before prove it correct or not.  I should be rigorous coding and testing as a developer. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Your `producers` do not have `multiprocessing.Process.daemon` propery set:

> **daemon**
>
> The process’s daemon flag, a Boolean value. This must be set before start() is called.
>
> The initial value is inherited from the creating process.
>
> When a process exits, it attempts to terminate all of its daemonic child processes.
>
> Note that a daemonic process is not allowed to create child processes. Otherwise a daemonic process would leave its children orphaned if it gets terminated when its parent process exits. Additionally, these are not Unix daemons or services, they are normal processes that will be terminated (and not joined) if non-daemonic processes have exited.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon

Just add `producer.daemon = True`:

```
...
producer = multiprocessing.Process(target=produce,args=(file_queue,row_queue))
producer.daemon = True
producer.start()
...
```

That should make it possible for the whole program to end when the `consumer` is joined.

By the way, you should probably `join` the producers too.

Comment: Calling `join` on the producers if they're not exiting on their own will just make the program hang. He'd need to fix whatevers keeping them from exiting in order for calling `join` to not cause a hang, in which cases there would be no need to make them daemons in the first place.

Comment: @dano yes, you're right. But since we don't know how the full `produce` function looks like, I just tried to keep it simple. I tend to use poison pill for my `Processes` and then join them, but I also set them `daemon=True` , so when the parent quit unexpectedly before issuing the poison pills, they won't hang.. But feel free to downvote..

Comment: @dano @Jan Spurny  hi guys, I past my `produce()` method, can you check it out?

Comment: @haifzhan My guess is that `row_queue` is filling up so that a call to `row_queue.put` is hanging, but without a complete example I can't say for sure. Try removing the max size from `row_queue` and see if the hang goes away.

Comment: @dano   I agree that the `row_queue` is filling up. `row = row_queue.get(timeout=60) `  I have invokded queue.get() in my consumer, and set timeout to 60 seconds. Therefore, if the queue is full, the `produce()` will be blocked until `row_queue` has space for new incoming rows, the `row_queue` should not block forever...